# best approach for converting a heavy website into a hybrid app

Tags: web, ibm-mobilefirst

what is the best approach to work with ibm worklight website which has lots of content ..should it made multipgage?if it is multipage how do we access worklight context on each page

Answer (score 0):

IMO there are multiple aspects you need to think about and take into account  with respect to your specific scenario and needs. Since you did not describe those in detail, I will try to generalise my suggestions:

- Your are not *required* to have an app per-se

  You could also re-design your website with [responsive web design](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/) in mind. This way, as your users load the website in either Desktop browser or Mobile browser apps, the website fits itself to the device's viewport size.
- If you do choose to create an app

  1. Not all aspects of your website must exist on the mobile app. Re-consider your strategy and find the right balance of what you should present to your end-users. Make it lighter
  2. Think mobile-first; the paradigm is different and so should be your approach and design: [UI Design Dos and Don'ts](https://developer.apple.com/design/tips/)
  3. As for the technical aspect, many UI framework provide ways to present "pages" within your app. Worklight can work with any of them. Read more about the challenges and solutions, here:

     - [Building a multi-page application](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/client-side-development-basics/building-multi-page-application/) tutorial
     - [Example application](https://github.com/IdanAdar/Multipage-Navigation-Using-jQM) showcasing multi-page navigation in Worklight 6.2 using jQuery Mobile
     - [Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-mobile%5D%5Bworklight%5D%20pages%20is%3Aquestion%20closed%3Ano%20duplicate%3Ano) about Worklight and multi-page apps

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking Worklight hybrid apps are single page apps: there is a single HTML page and we never navigate to a new "URL". However from the UI point of view the user sees what appears to be multiple pages, typically this is achieved by manipulating the DOM of the single page. For example we have a DIV for each "page" the user sees, and we navigate by showing and hiding those DIVs.

With that philosophy in mind your question about accessing the Worklight context now becomes trivial: we're on a single page, so the context is always avaialble.

As Idan says it usually simplest to implement such a single-page, multi-view app by using a JavaScript framework that manages the navigation. Many folks these days use angularJs. Using such frameworks we can decompose the app into a number of small HTML and JS files that are dynamically loaded, from the app perspective it's still a single page but from a development perspective we now have finer-grained artefacts that allow easier parallel development in a multi-person team. When you have an with many 10s of "pages" such decomposition really pays off.